# How do I upgrade my activesupport gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, activesupport

I’m on Mac Sierra.  I was having trouble creating a new project in my workspace, so I decided to check my Rails version.  I ran this command

```
localhost:workspace davea$ rails --version
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:310:in `to_specs': Could not find 'activesupport' (= 5.0.0.1) - did find: [activesupport-4.2.5.1] (Gem::MissingSpecVersionError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0:/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1428:in `each'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1428:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1410:in `activate'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:68:in `block in gem'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `gem'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I don't know why I'm getting the above but it seems like I have a problem with ActiveSupport.  How do I upgrade the version of ActiveSupport that I’m using?

**Edit:** Here’s the output of the suggestions …

```
localhost:workspace davea$ bundle install
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

localhost:workspace davea$ bundle exec rails --version
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` before? Besides that, it's a good idea use `bundle exec rails --version` instead of `rails version`

Comment: Edited my question to include what happened when I ran your commands.  Basically both resulted in "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory" errors.

Comment: Try reinstall rails using `gem install rails`

Comment: That worked.  thx!